# How to add computed column to model in dbml

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, rdlc, calculated-columns

How to add an computed column to the model class.

I have two models in view,

1. `User`
2. `City`

`User` is connected to `City` with the `CityID` (FK contraint) and `CityName` is in the `City` model

I wanted the computed column in `User` model because the **.rdlc** report does not seems to get value from the `City` model which is connected to `User` (in dbml).

Currently when I add the new property to the model then it gives error when the linq query using that model executes.

> Invalid column name 'UserCityName'

which means it tries to select `CityName` from `User` from database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinqToSQL generate entity as partial class, so you can add additional column to your entity by add new class and add following code.

Example:

```
namespace YourEntityNameSpace
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public string UserAdditionalText
        { 
            get
            {
                // your code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

1. Expand `Model.dbml` in your solution window, you will find `Model.dbml.layout` and `Model.designer.cs`.
2. Open `Model.designer.cs`, it contains auto-generated class from your database
3. Search for text `public partial class User`. Now you can see, auto-generated class is partial class which mean you can define your class in separate file. [Read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
4. Add new class to your project, use same namespace and class name as in your auto-generated file.
5. Add additional property to User class, you can access all property and member inside auto-generated class.

Comment: I create the model from the dbml designer and dbml file has auto-generated model classes, changes done manually in the model class will not get lost when in future I make changes from dbml designer ?

Comment: Sure, you can look at auto-generated model class, it's partial. What you need to do is add new class to your project then change its namespace to the namespace of your model (`YourEntityNameSpace` in my answer).

Comment: So u mean create separate class `User` under different namespace ?

Comment: What? I mean you can add new file to your project, use same namespace and same class name. You also need to add partial keyword to the class in new file. I just update my answer, and it has a link about partial class inside it. :)

Comment: Yes, I knew about Partial classes, anyways. Thanks it works. :D